# Resize PDF without compression and version change

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF that is in a slightly off format.

I try to resize the PDF without changing its version or reducing its quality.

All online pdf-resizer that I have tried have changed one of the properties.

I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185145/convert-pdf-to-a-different-page-size-us-letter-a4) that

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --paper a4paper in.pdf
```

will resize the PDF without reducing its quality. However the version will be changed from 1.4 to 1.5.

If I then try to change the version as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/184288/how-to-convert-a-pdf-document-to-an-older-version):

```
 gs                        \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite        \
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
  -o output.pdf            \
     in.pdf
```

The file is extremely pixelated.

Any way, how to resize a PDF in Ubuntu, keeping version 1.4 and avoiding pixel-resolution?

Comment: does this online tool help? https://pdfcompressor.com/

Comment: @User24601 if I understand it correctly, pdfcompressor only compresses pdfs, and is not resizing the format? I founda php resizer that converts to pdf 1.4 at https://neevia.com/